# Random Color com Twitch Chat Widget

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a JSS for twitch that generates random colors in the div where the people's names are in the chat, I managed to generate the random colors, but I wanted this to happen to every person who sent a message, as if it were a message, a random color in the name to make something very colorful, but the function that I just managed to have at least this color change has a time interval and makes the color change what is not what I wanted to generate. Can someone give me a light on how I change this JavaScript so that it works and generate random colors for each person who sends a message? I'll put the image as it is and a part of the code here (https://youtu.be/kiPQLpaIyhg)

Here is the CSS where the background color of this section is, I wanted it to take random colors

```
#log .meta {
  max-width: 500px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 0.1em;
 text-align: left;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #832839;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

And here the command in JSS that I used to make the colors change, but making them change according to the time

```
window.setInterval(function(){

  var randomColor = '#'+ ('000000' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)).slice(-6);

  $('.meta').css({
    'background-color' : randomColor,
  });

}, 1000);
```

Does anyone know how I change this JSS so that the color will be generated for each different message and not keep changing according to the time interval? I tried to remove the time interval and other changes but I couldn't. I don't know much about JSS so I wanted this help.

Answer (score 0):

use this for generate a random color:

```
var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
```

Comment: I'm managing to generate the random colors, the point is that they change as seen in the video, and I don't know how to generate the colors without the "window.setInterval", and the colors are fixed, even though they are random